# PostgreSQL No Auto Increment function?

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a test application coded in Java for creating an indexed and non indexed table in a MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle and Firebird database (Amongst other things).

Is it simply a case that PostgreSQL doesnt allow the auto increment feature? If not, what is the normal procedure for having an indexed coloumn?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use [`SERIAL`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) in PostgreSQL to generate auto increment field,

For eg:-

```
CREATE TABLE user (
userid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
username VARCHAR(16) UNIQUE NOT NULL
)
```

This will create userid as auto-increment primary key indexed.
If you don't want this as primary key, just remove PRIMARY KEY.

Answer (score 3):

Use a column of type `SERIAL`. It works the same way as `AUTOINCREMEMT` on some other DBs. (Check the docs for other features you can use with it.)

Answer (score 3):

With current Postgres, you can just use SERIAL for the column type.

With older versions of Postgres, you can implement this using SEQUENCE; the relevant procedure is:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE mytable_myid_seq;
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN myid SET DEFAULT NEXTVAL('mytable_myid_seq');
```

A good article on this is [MySQL versus PostgreSQL: Adding an Auto-Increment Column to a Table](http://pointbeing.net/weblog/2008/03/mysql-versus-postgresql-adding-an-auto-increment-column-to-a-table.html)

Comment: Thanks, my first time with postgre :)